# Compare coherence values, pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I wanted to find values satisfying the condition, here is code:

```
from scipy import signal

   s1 = pd.DataFrame(fdata)
   s2 = pd.DataFrame(fdata1)

   f, Cxy = signal.coherence(s1[0], s2[0], fs=2.5e9, nperseg=1024)

   m = Cxy.max()

   if (m > 0.5 and f < 2e7): #condition to be satisfied, I'll be grateful for showing me condition for f in range(200, 2e7)
           True
```

signal.coherence is returning two ndarrays, `f` ndarray and `Cxy` ndarray.

The problem is that `f` and `Cxy` creates pairs and then `f` is the argument for `m`.
I read a lot about pandas, but I don't know how to put condition on f ndarray.

The return form coherence function is for example:

```
 f returns        Cxy returns
    0.              1.73e-5
    1.23.           1.57e-4
    1.43.           1.93e-2
    1.63            1.37e-5
    .               .
    .               .
    .               .
```

if `m = Cxy.max()` = 1.93e-2 and `f` should be `f` < 1.23 for `m` (here for `m`, `f` is 1.43, so it is false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f is a numpy array. You can select values from it by [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
f_sel = f[(f>200) & (f<2e7)]   # don't forget the parantheses!
```

or

```
import numpy as np
f_sel = f[np.logical_and(f>200, f<2e7)]
```

---

As you mentioned pandas in your question: you can convert the arrays back to a dataframe by `f_df = pd.DataFrame(f)`. In this case a dataframe with just one column named `0` is created.  You can select values the same way as above: `f_df[(f_df[0]>200) & (f_df[0]<2e7)]`. If your dataframe has only one column you'd normally use a series `f_s = pd.Series(f)` and select like `f_s[(f_s>200) & (f_s<2e7)]`.

---

You can combine `f` and `Cxy` into a dataframe like that:

```
result = pd.DataFrame( {'f': f, 'Cxy': Cxy})
```

and then select like that:

```
result.query('Cxy > 0.5 & f > 200 & f < 2e7')
```

Comment: The problem is that `f` and `Cxy` creates pairs and then `f` is the argument for `m`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it: in your example m is a scalar (the max of Cxy), how can f be the argument for m? Do you need the f-value for m? Maybe you could describe it in some more detail what you want to get.

Comment: please see my update - does this answer your question?

Comment: `result.query` replaces if statement? Can I use if here?

Comment: `results.query` selects row to given condition, reading your updated question this is probably not what you want. Where comes the `1.23` in "f should be < 1.23" from?

Comment: the f value for the maximum Cxy you can get by `result.iloc[result.Cxy.argmax(),:].f`

Comment: `1.23` is empirical parameter

Comment: OK, so it'll be `final_result = result.iloc[result.Cxy.argmax(),:].f < 1.23` which will be `False` in your case.